# How do I filter items by email field in Podio API for PHP?

Tags: php, podio

I need to get an item from a collection of items that contains the email address `<my-email>`

Here is the structure of that part of the object:

```
[2] => PodioEmailItemField Object
                            (
                                [__attributes:PodioObject:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [field_id] => <my-field-id>
                                        [type] => email
                                        [external_id] => email
                                        [label] => Email
                                        [values] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [type] => work
                                                        [value] => <my-email>
                                                    )

                                            )
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
$items = PodioItem::filter($app_id, array('filters'=>
                                    array(
                                          'email'=>
                                           array(
                                                'values'=>
                                                 array(
                                                       array(
                                                             'value'=>'<my-email>'))))));
```

but i keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Invalid value {"values": [{"value": "<my-email>"}]} (object): must be array"
```

What am I missing here?

I would prefer to find this item using the `external_id` rather than the `field_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = \PodioItem::filter($app_id, [
    'filters' => [
        // replace 123456 with field ID for your field with email type
        '123456' => [
            'test1@example.com', 
            // 'test2@example.com',
            // 'test3@example.com'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

In the "Developer" section of your app you can find the field ID for your field with email type.
[image: "Developer"]

If you will call filter by multiple emails, then Podio will return the result, if one of them will be found.